# Make a specific string Upper case in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I'm trying to change the specific string to upper case my code is

```
update $table 
set work_log_history = concat(("$created_by response on $toDate $history"||chr(10)),work_log_history) 
where id="$id"
```

In the above query I want to make `$created_by` string UPPERCASE.

Comment: pass 3 arguments to concat and then use upper(string) function to make the string uppercase

Comment: Try this:update $table set  work_log_history=concat(("UPPER($created_by) response on $toDate $history"||chr(10)),work_log_history) where id="$id"

Comment: "UPPER(namburi) response on 07/12/2017"  the result is like this UPPER  is also appending to it.@Diabolus

Comment: Thanx @ViswanathPolaki   it worked.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think UPPER() function should work for you in this situation? See the documentation here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

So your code would look like:

```
update $table 
set  work_log_history=concat((UPPER($created_by)," response on $toDate $history"||chr(10)),work_log_history) 
where id="$id"
```

Comment: I wanted to convert only $created_by  to uppercase in your case the whole string is converted into Uppercase.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know I've separated out the UPPER($created_by)in the code above

Answer (score 0):

Use upper() function

`update table_name set field =UPPER(filed) where id=1`

Answer (score 0):

" update $table set work_log_history=concat(UPPER('$created_by '),('\tresponse on $toDate $input_data->{comment}'||chr(10)),work_log_history) where id='$id' "   and it worked fine.